# Python dictionary to json cannot understand the basics

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary

In this example I can create a JSON out of a dict with desired structure.

```
import json

jsondata = {}
jsondata = {'type':'add', 'id':'','fields':{'message':'text', 'from':'email@email.com'}}
jsfields = jsondata, jsondata
print json.dumps(jsfields)
```

This is output which is desired.

```
[
  {
    "id": "",
    "type": "add",
    "fields": {
      "from": "email@email.com",
      "message": "text"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "",
    "type": "add",
    "fields": {
      "from": "email@email.com",
      "message": "text"
    }
  }
]
```

Now what I do not understand is how can I add more json objects into this single array?

From this point I do not have a clue how to add the same content as a next array in jsfields.

```
{
    "id": "",
    "type": "add",
    "fields": {
      "from": "email@email.com",
      "message": "text"
    }

}
```

Comment: I am embarassed to answer my own question. But I just have to append dict to a list.

Comment: It happens to the best of us :P

Answer (score 1):

`jsfields = jsondata, jsondata`

This line creates a **tuple** containing two copies of `jsondata`. A tuple is somewhat like a list, but is immutable, meaning that you cannot add anything to it after it is created.

You probably want to do this to create a list:

`jsfields = [jsondata, jsondata]`

This creates a list with two copies of `jsondata` in it. You can then add more entries pretty easily:

`jsfields.append(some_other_dict)`

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the JSON string back to a python object, then add a new item the list, and then convert it to JSON again.

```
import json

jsondata = {}
jsondata = {'type':'add', 'id':'','fields':{'message':'text', 'from':'email@email.com'}}
jsfields = jsondata, jsondata
json_output = json.dumps(jsfields) # this is where your old output is
new_json = json.loads(json_output) # convert the old output back to python object
new_json.append(jsondata) # add new item to the list
print(json.dumps(new_json)) # convert to JSON again
```